# Проблема с местом на диске

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

Команда ds показывает, что из 200Gb свободно 0, а программа ncdu / - что используется всего 6Gb. Как найти то, что съело все место?

Comment: Перезагружаться пробовали?

Comment: Например `du -hd 1` и далее искать по уровням.

Comment: тоже самое - 6Gb. Перегружаться не пробовал. Может помочь?

Comment: @IK место, вероятно, "занято" файлом (файлами), который был отмечен удалённым, но чей дескриптор не был освобождён (т. е. всё ещё используется). Проверьте результаты команды `lsof | egrep 'DEL|dele'`

Comment: @gbg Перезагрузка помогла. Теперь занято 36% Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась из-за неправильной работы скрипта. Обнаружилось, что после перезагрузки место стало быстро уменьшаться. К сожалению, я не смог определить, куда именно он сваливал данные. Скрипт исправил и места теперь 95%